# Is there a way to preserve macros in an excel file(xls) while trying to append data in the existing file using xlrt ,xlwt and xlutils?

Tags: python, excel, automation

I am basically trying to add data to concerned cells in an existing excel file(.xls) using xlrd xlwt and xlutils. I am able to put the data to the concerned cell in the file, however, the macro buttons are not preserved in this process. Is there any way that I can append my data to the xls file without disturbing the macros(or the original file)?

I tried something like this to incorporate the values to the required cells:

```
    import xlwt
    import xlrd
    import xlutils.copy import copy
    rb=xlrd.open_workbook('try.xls')
    wb=copy(rb)
    w_sheet=wb.get_sheet(0)
    w_sheet.write(0,2,15)
    wb.save('try.xls')
```

I am doing it this way as I need to put some values in an existing xls file and then use that to perform further operations using the buttons present in the file. I am new to this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Excel file format to include macros is ".xlsxm" if not macros are not saved iirc.

Comment: I tried saving the file in ".xlsm" format but Excel couldn't open the file.It said that extension should match the format of file.

Comment: @SolarMike `xls` can contain macros too. It is the old binary Excel file format from excel versions (before 2003 I believe).

Comment: @Hearty The issue here probably is the python library you use does not support macros. Check the documentation of the library.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I couldn't find any other library that supports reading/writing to an xls file, so I tried with this one.